# ASP.NET MVC 5 Session cookie getting automatically added to response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

After adding a cookie to the response on the landing page of my site, I'm seeing a cookie get added to subsequent responses automatically. This cookie has the same name as the cookie I added on the landing page, but has no value and no expiration date.

This is the code that creates the cookie:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("dcGlUCookie");
cookie.Value = "dct=0&dcs=627&dcl=8644&dcu=0&dcp=0&dca=&dcut=-1";
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(90);
cookie.HttpOnly = true;
cookie.Secure = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

This is what the cookies look like after the landing page is loaded:

[image]

This is the cookie that is getting added automatically to Response.Cookies while loading a second page:

[image]

This is what the cookies look like after loading a second page:

[image]

I can't find anything that explains the behavior. While I could get rid of this session cookie on subsequent requests manually, it seems like I'm missing something. Is there some way of creating the cookie or configuring the app so this doesn't happen?

Comment: Can you also share on your post where do you set your cookie and your code for your cookie setup?

Comment: As requested, added the code that creates the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this was happening because the layout page was referencing one of the cookie's values. Just referencing a cookie automatically adds it to the response's cookies, not sure why.

I fixed by passing the cookie value through the ViewBag.